# Checking While Loop with if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

The while loop and if statement work through the first iteration. After it completes and it prints "Do you want another time?" and I input "Y" the program terminates and I don't know why. My logic and syntax seem to be correct but there is always flaws that I cant see with my own eyes. I would appreciate it if someone can point the flaw out.

```
while (!check) {
    str = in.nextLine();
    if (in.hasNextLine() && str.equals("Y")) {
        hours = ran.nextInt(11) + 1;
        minutes = ran.nextInt(60);
        if (minutes < 10) {
            System.out.println(hours + ":" + "0" + minutes);
        } else {
            System.out.println(hours + ":" + minutes);
        }
        System.out.println("Do you want another time?");

    } else {
        check = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be checking to see if you have another line in the buffer; you can just explicitly check the input you get back through `str` instead.  The likely reason you're exiting out of the loop the first time is due to `in.hasNextLine()` being false.

So, this means that you'd change your `if` statement to:

```
if(str.equals("Y")) {

}
```

Comment: See I didn't know that. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to see if there is a next line (`in.hasNextLine()`), after you have *already* read it.

Try this way:

```
       while (!check) {
            if(in.hasNextLine()){
                System.out.println("Do you want another time?");
                str = in.nextLine();
                if("Y".equals(str)){
                    hours = ran.nextInt(11) + 1;
                    minutes = ran.nextInt(60);
                    if (minutes < 10) {
                        System.out.println(hours + ":" + "0" + minutes);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(hours + ":" + minutes);
                    }
                    System.out.println("Do you want another time?");
                }
            }else{
                check = true;
            }
        }
```

Ok, here's a nicer way to do this whole thing:

```
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println("Do you want another time?");
        if("Y".equals(in.nextLine())){
            //do what you want to do
        }else{
          //perhaps you want to break, or whatever you want to do
          break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's a lot more convoluted than what's required for this.

Comment: @Makoto absolutely, but it is what OP has, I will suggest a better loop soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here Is what you looking for.

```
while (!check) {        

        hours = ran.nextInt(11) + 1;
        minutes = ran.nextInt(60);

        if (minutes < 10) {
            System.out.println(hours + ":" + "0" + minutes);
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println(hours + ":" + minutes);
        }

        System.out.println("Do you want another time?");
        str = in.nextLine();

        if(str.equals("Y"))
          check = false;
        else
        check = true;   

}
```

What I changed is, I am comparing the str after taking the input.
if its "Y" it will continue otherwise it will go out of the while loop.

Comment: Nit:  you could just say `check = str.equals("Y");`

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to be bit explanatory.

Comment: @Makoto excuse me, what does "Nit" means? (Not an english native so, want to know if I see this again in the future)

Comment: @Frakcool:  "Nit" as in ["nitpick"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nitpick).  Just pointing out a fault I saw.

Comment: @Makoto I would not say it as a fault, but a better way of coding.